# Flux Utils TypeError: Class constructor App cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, flux, reactjs-flux

I am trying to implement a Flux Util container on the following React component:

```
class App extends React.Component<{},AppState> {
 constructor(props:Readonly<{}>){
    super(props);   
 }
 static getStores(){
    return [ArticlesStore];
 }

 static calculateState(prevState:AppState):AppState{
    return {
        articles:ArticlesStore.getState()
    }
 }
 render() {
    return (
        <main>
            <Navbar></Navbar>
            <Routes></Routes>
        </main>
    );
 }
}


interface AppState{
 /**
  * Articles retrived from the ArticlesState to be used in the rendering of the page
  */
 articles:ArticlesStoreState;
}

export default Container.create(App);
```

In implementing the required code for creating a container, I followed both the example provided on the flux website and some other code found on GitHub as reference. But when running this code, I get the following error:

```
`TypeError: Class constructor App cannot be invoked without 'new'.`
```

(I am using typescript)

Does anyone have any idea what might cause this error this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am having the same problem. Any solutions yet?

Comment: Haven't tried to find a fix any longer and just moved to Redux. I recommend you do the same if possible or use 'useReducer()' hook since they are easier to implement that Flux Stores

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Anyone has solved this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and it's possible that is happening for you because you're trying to run Flux in ES6 like I am.

If that is the case, then, according to [this](https://github.com/facebook/flux/issues/351) issue in their GitHub repo, Flux Containers still don't support ES6 yet.

The possible (ugly) workaround as seen in the comments is to do the following:

```
/// FluxContainerConverter.js

module.exports = {
    convert: function(containerClass) {
        const tmp = containerClass;
        containerClass = function(...args) {
            return new tmp(...args);
        };
        containerClass.prototype = tmp.prototype;
        containerClass.getStores = tmp.getStores;
        containerClass.calculateState = tmp.calculateState;
        return containerClass;
    }
};
```

Now you can use it to create your FluxContainer like this:

```
var fluxContainerConverter = require('./FluxContainerConverter');

Container.create(
    fluxContainerConverter.convert(MyComponent));
```

Comment: what is module here?